# EnableQuery always perform SingleOrDefault on IEnumerable<T> result

Tags: odata, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-core-3.1

I have the following Api Endpoint:

```
     [EnableQuery()]
     [Route("rankingreport", Name = "GetRankingReport")]
     public IQueryable<RefereeRankingReport> GetRankingReport()
     {
         var data = (from r in _context.RefereeRankings
                    join m in _context.Referees on r.RefereeId equals m.ID
                    join mg in _context.RefereeGradings on r.GradingId equals mg.ID
                    select new RefereeRankingReport
                    {
                        ...
                    })
                    .AsNoTracking();

         return data;
     }
```

I was able to query this endpoint in ASP.NET MVC as such `http://url.base/api/referee/rankingreport` and got all the results. If needed I then add the odata filters etc on the url to filter the data. `http://url.base/api/referee/rankingreport?$filter=GradingId eq 5&$orderby=GradingId,Ranking`

However I'm busy upgrading to .net core 3.1 and seeing an exception where it will always return the result as SingleOrDetault. I don't know why it wants to do this as the method is clearly returning IQueryable.

In the startup I have declared this:

```
services.AddOData();

...

app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
            {
                routeBuilder.EnableDependencyInjection();
                routeBuilder.Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Select().MaxTop(null);
            });
```

I don't have the odata route defined, because I don't need or want it.

What am I missing to get this to return the resulting list or records as expected?

Answer (score 1):

In .NET Core 3.1 - Endpoint routing isn't supported (yet), you have to have the OData route there for your functionality to work.

Comment: Thanks @Hassan. I will keep an eye on your blog there for the updates. Once it is possible, I will then post an update here if someone don't beat me to it.